# AnsiString to Double C++

Tags: c++builder, ansistring

I am trying to convert an `AnsiString` to a `double`, but after running the programm, it says "20.60 is not a valid floating point".

```
AnsiString Temperatur

RE_Temperatur->Text = Temperatur;

Chart1->Series[0]->AddXY(DT_Uhrzeit->Time, RE_Temperatur->Text.ToDouble(), 
"", clRed);
```

The value for `Temperatur` comes from a SerialPort connection from my Arduino and delivers something like 20.60 and so on. When I cut the string to the first 2 digits it is working fine. Guess the `.` has something to do with the error but I dont know how to solve it.

EDIT //
I now tried to just replace the "." with a "," with following code:

```
    RE_Temperatur->Text = StringReplace(RE_Temperatur->Text, ".", ",", 
    TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
```

Now I get an Error Message "20,60 is not a valid floating point". Its so frustrating :/

Comment: Where is this `AnsiString` class defined? Is it possible that it's locale-aware and your locale has `,` instead of `.` as the decimal separator?

Comment: I am using Codegear, forgot to mention, where do i have to look this up? is it something in the settings of the compiler i am using?

Comment: It's also possible the Arduino is providing data (e.g. non-printable characters) that cannot be scanned as a floating point value.

Comment: The Arduino is sending Strings to the Serial port and within my C++ Programm i am Converting the Strings i get to a Ansistring to place it in my Edit Box.

Comment: @Angew - `AnsiString` is a vendor specific type associated with the Borland/Inprise/Embarcadero C++ Builder product.

Comment: What is the content of `DecimalSeparator` variable?

Comment: @Angew: AnsiString is defined in C++Builder. It emulates the Delphi datatype of the same name. But that is certainly not the problem. It is in use for many, many years already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple piece of code in a new console program:

```
AnsiString Temperatur = "12.45"; // locale independent
AnsiString Temperatur2 = "12,45"; // correct in my German locale

double temp = StrToFloat(Temperatur, TFormatSettings::Invariant());
double temp2 = StrToFloat(Temperatur2); // In my case: German locale!

printf("%8.4f %8.4f\n", temp, temp2);
```

The output is:

```
 12.4500  12.4500
```

You can see that it works as expected. Note that on my system, the **comma** is the decimal separator for the locale, and yet this code works fine with the period as decimal separator, because of the invariant format settings.

So make your choice: use `TFormatSettings::Invariant()` if you need independence of the locale, but don't use it if you want it to use the decimal separator for the locale of the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [StrToFloat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat) it has a second version that takes a `TFormatSettings` object which you can use to specify a specific `DecimalSeperator`. BTW it does not return a float as its name might suggest it returns an `Extended` aka `long double`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have no clue how to implement this in my code. Do you have any short example for me?

Comment: Instead of a specific TFormatSetitngs, you can also use the prefedined Invariant FormatSettings (see help), to get a language-agnostic version, with `'.'` as DecimalSeparator.

Comment: @kevin: `Chart1->Series[0]->AddXY(DT_Uhrzeit->Time, StrToFloat(Temperatur, TFormatSettings::Invariant()), 
"", clRed);`

Comment: FWIW, it is called `StrToFloat` because it converts a string to a *floating point value*. In Delphi, the `float` type is called `Single`, for *single precision*. At the time this was designed, compatibility with C or C++ was not a big deal yet, so they never considered calling it `StrToExtended` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that your problem is the decimal point. The character used for it is one of the Windows environment variables and can vary from computer to computer. There are winapi calls to receive it but I do not remember them ...

The problem with `AnsiString("1.23").ToDouble()` is that `catch/try` will not catch the exception (at least on my compiler **BDS2006**). There are workarounds. I am using `atoi()` instead which is not crashing but rather truncate to integer when invalid character present so it can be used to detect the correct decimal point character and conversion:

```cpp
char _floating_point_char=' ';         // decimal point separator
AnsiString   strnum (AnsiString s,int sig=1,int pnt=1,int hex=0,char dot=_floating_point_char);
double       str2num(AnsiString s,int sig=1,int pnt=1,int hex=0,char dot=_floating_point_char);

AnsiString strnum(AnsiString s,int sig,int pnt,int hex,char dot)
    {
    if (dot==' ')
        {
        float x;
        x=atof("0.5"); if (x>=0.25) _floating_point_char='.';
        x=atof("0,5"); if (x>=0.25) _floating_point_char=',';
        dot=_floating_point_char;
        }

    int i,l,a,e,e0,exp=pnt;
    AnsiString q="";
    l=s.Length();
    if (hex) exp=0;     // exponent is e,E so it colide with hex e,E
    e0=0; for (i=1;i<=l;i++)
        {
        e=0;
        a=s[i];
        if ((a>='0')&&(a<='9'))       { e=1; q+=char(a  ); sig=0; }
        if ((a>='A')&&(a<='F'&&(hex))){ e=1; q+=char(a  ); sig=0; }
        if ((a>='a')&&(a<='f'&&(hex))){ e=1; q+=char(a  ); sig=0; }
        if ((a=='e')||(a=='E'))
         if (!hex)   { if (!exp) break; e=1; q+=char('e'); exp=0; sig=1; pnt=0; e0=0; }
        if (a=='+')  { if (!sig) break; e=1;               sig=0; }
        if (a=='-')  { if (!sig) break; e=1; q+=char(a  ); sig=0; }
        if (a=='.')  { if (!pnt) break; e=1; q+=char(dot); pnt=0; }
        if (a==',')  { if (!pnt) break; e=1; q+=char(dot); pnt=0; }
        if ((e0)&&(!e)) break;
        e0|=e;
        }
    if (q.Length()<=0) q="0";
    return q;
    }
double str2num(AnsiString s,int sig,int pnt,int hex,char dot)
    {
    return atof(strnum(s,sig,pnt,hex,dot).c_str());
    }
```

It simply detect if `.` or `,` is the right one and then replace it in string before conversion... Of coarse fetching the correct decimal point character from **winapi** is safer as the decimal point separator can be anything... You can ignore the `hex` part I am using this for any kind of numbers ...

Comment: ISTM that trToFloat will do, especially when used with TFormatSettings.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yes but I use this instead because my apps runs all over the world and the decimal point is different on each machine/language/locale_settings but the `*.ini` and config files are usually shared and using `TFormatSettings` require to know which one is used which is luxury I do  not have as each user prefers something different. This approach will work when you have string in wrong format inspite of that you do not know which decimal point is used and which should be...

Comment: So use TFormatSettings::Invariant, which is a predefined locale-invariant format settings. In other words, that is the same all over the world. If you also use that TFormatSettings to **write** your data too, you can be sure it is roundtrip (i.e. data in == data out) and such issues don't happen. Otherwise, if the data are locale-dependent, use StrToFloat *without* it. That will use the locale of the user.

Comment: FWIW, TFormatSettings::Invariant is mainly compatible with the US locale, so decimal separator is a dot (full stop, period) and thousands separator is a comma (but the latter only for output, not used for input). And the current default FormatSettings are initialized with what the winapi provides, so there is no need to do that manually.